# PHP echo always goes to JQuery $.ajax error block

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, response

First off - no, this is not a cross site request issue. The Javascript and PHP are coming from the same server.

Here is the Javascript code.

```
var form_data = {
    email:    email,
    password: password
};

$.ajax({
    type:        'POST',
    url:         '/Login.php',
    data:         form_data,
    success:      function(jsonResponse){
        console.log("Login returned via 'success'.");
    },
    error:        function (xhr, textStatus, error) {
        console.log("Login returned via 'error'.");

        // These are always empty:

        console.dir(xhr);
        console.dir(textStatus);
        console.dir(error);
    }
});
```

Here is the PHP code:

```
$response = array('success' => true);
header('content-type: application/json'); // This line makes no difference.
echo json_encode($response);
return;
```

No matter what I do, the console ALWAYS hits the "Login returned via 'error'." code.

Further, after it returns, it forces a page refresh on the client.

I have very little hair left to pull out!

ANY help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is your php script returing a 200 status code? Anything else will generally be interpreted as an error.

Comment: is this on a unix server? `Login.php` is not the same as `login.php`. Instead of a fixed+useless error message,w hy not have `console.log('Login return: ' + error);` and have the system TELL you what's wrong?

Comment: Check the response via your favorite browsers developer tools. See if it returns with a successful HTTP status as 200.

Comment: try calling the php on its own through a url and skip all the ajax and see what is shown.

Comment: Check the Network tab in your browser developer tools, to see what the response code was. And check the webserver and PHP logs on the server.

Comment: @MarcB Don't you see the OP's attempt at logging `xhr`, `textStatus`, and `error` right after logging "Login returned via 'error'" ? The comment says "These are always empty:"

Comment: Everyone had good points, which I had already tried, but Nathan got it. I had tried going straight to the URL, but only AFTER the browser had already tried it via Javascript. The code was in a different state by then. So, this time I switched to the URL just before the Javascript was about to kick in. That shows it WAS returning and error, so of course it was going to the $.ajax error block. I am still stumped with the logic error, but it is separate from this issue, so I'll fight with it and ask another question if I am still stuck. Thanks! Now - how to I 'accept' Nathan's answer?

Answer (score -2):

Try

```
$response = array('success' => true);
header('content-type: application/json'); // This line makes no difference.
echo json_encode($response);
exit;
```

also make sure no other output is sent from the script and check return headers in the console